# Creating an Ctablctrl on a CFrameWnd

Tags: c++, mfc

I want to create a mfc window that has tabs on top.
I cannot find a good tutorial or example of this.
Can someone give me a link to a good tutorial of example?

please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install the Visual C++ Feature Pack. It comes with newer libraries to do this.

Comment: The Feature Pack was rolled into SP1 for VC++ 2008. And is already in VC++ 2010.

Answer (score 2):

You mean like this?

[MFC app in VS 2010 http://blogs.msdn.com/photos/vcblog/images/9927511/original.aspx](http://blogs.msdn.com/photos/vcblog/images/9927511/original.aspx)

Here is a walkthrough that should take you where you need to be: [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20150906182627/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2009/11/23/teched-europe-demo-session-face-lifting-mfc-applications-on-windows-7.aspx)